# Icons and images in Mac application using Xamrin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I am converting a `windows forms` app to `Mac`. The strategy that I choose was to create a `xamarin forms` project. Later on add `Xamarin.Mac project` to it and use xamarin forms NetStandard code to run on `MacOS`. The original `win forms` app have two  `.ico images`. One to show on the `screen` and another one as `Desktop` icon.How to use these images within my Mac Project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody answered but I find out the way on my own.I have to deal with several problems while converting the `Windows form` app to `Xamarin.Mac` App.I use `Visual Studio for Mac` for Creating `Xamarin.Forms` project and adding Xamarin.Mac project to it. Lots of the C# logic run out of the box for Xamarin.Mac. But I have to rewrite the whole UI in `Xaml`. I only had two `.ico` images. I need to convert them to a format which can be used on Mac. 
I decided to use free and open sourced [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) software. I used `GIMP` to change the format of the images to `.png`.

After this I save the .png image in `Resources folder` of Xamarin.Mac with `Build Action` as `Bundle Resource`.Write this xaml for the image:

```
<Image  x:Name="LogoImage" Margin="-100,-100,-100,-120"/>
```

Set Source of the image in code behind like this:

```
LogoImage.Source =ImageSource.FromFile("logo.png");
```

Note that `ImageSource.FromFile` is used for `Local images` saved in each `platform project`. Whereas `ImageSource.FromResource` is used for `images Embedded` in `Shared Project` and have `Build Action` as `Embedded Resource`. The first image is displaying on the UI screen.

Now comes the second image used as `Application icon` in `winforms app`. Here the things work `differently`. In modern app development the general practice is to provide image for `every resolution` and `device form factor` the app will run on. Apart from that the different size images are required for showing in different places. e.g Image for `Dock`, `Menubar` and `Activity Monitor` on Mac.  So I created image for every resolution required with GIMP.

Finally open the Assets.xcassets file from the Mac project. scroll down and find empty boxes for mac images of different resolutions. Add matching images by clicking on each box and selecting correct image size. For details [Go here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app-icon/). Finally `bin` and `obj` folders need to be `deleted` from both `projects`. `Clean` and `ReBuild` the `Xamarin.Mac` project. **Yes**, the images are integrated in the app and `displaying` when I `deploy` the app.